# Why is the wrong parameter being passed here?

Tags: y86

I'm new to Y86 and am trying to write a recursive multiplication function, but the wrong parameter keeps being passed.

The code that calls the multiplication function:

```
  square:
  irmovl $4, %ebx
  pushl  %ebx           # push argument
  rrmovl %ebx, %edx   #set it equal to the number being squared 
  pushl  %edx

  call rmult

  popl %edx  
  popl %ebx
  ret
```

And the actual multiplication code:

```
rmult:
pushl %ebp
rrmovl %esp,%ebp
mrmovl 8(%ebp),%ebx         #ebx = y
irmovl $0,%eax      
rrmovl %ebx,%edi    
subl %ebx,%eax      
je rec_multend

rrmovl %ebx,%esi
irmovl $1,%eax      
subl %eax,%esi      

pushl %ebx      
pushl %esi      
call rmult 
mrmovl 12(%ebp),%edx    #edx = x
popl %esi
popl %ebx


addl %edx,%edi 
rec_multend:
 popl %ebp
 ret
```

I pass in 4 for both x and y as the function calling them is squaring a number and so they should be the same, but at the line:

```
mrmovl 12(%ebp),%edx    #edx = x
```

It passes in 2 instead of the 4 that I initially put in there, which ends up returning a value of 13 rather than 16.

From my limited understanding of Y86, "mrmovl 8(%ebp),%ebx" should return the second parameter which I set equal to Y and "mrmovl 12(%ebp),%edx" should return the first parameter equal to X, with both of them being passed in as 4.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] including the code you use to call this function?

Comment: Just added the calling function